# Kitematic (docker) - pointing to a host on a docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using kitematic but when i launch it on MacOS it shows my local docker installation.

Via the command line - i can use docker by first doing

```
docker-machine env remote-mac
```

How can I have kitematic use the machine too ?

Anybody know, i checked the documentation but can't seem to find any reference to it

Thanks in advance